# Bootstrap 4 responsive navbar vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and  have navigation with horizontal items on my page. On small devices this menu collapses and menu items are still in horizontal line. What should I do to change it to vertical so items are one per each line?

Comment: Note that Bootstrap 4 is not stable as it's still in beta

Comment: Thanks for reminding me at that. I do understand that I should't use it in production but for now I am using it only on a student project which won't be (at least at the beginning) in production and there are still things to be done.

Comment: it would be helpfull for others if you post codes (Not your whole project ofcourse) you have tried by yourself or think where the mistakes are in the code, this will also help you receiving answers and suggestions. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/763tcf9r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bootstrap 4, the breakpoints have changed. You should override the navbar CSS like this if you want it to be vertical on small screens:

```
@media(max-width: 544px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
        float: none;
        margin-left: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
    }
    .navbar .collapse.in, .navbar .collapsing  {
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

**Demo** http://codeply.com/go/Ar1H2G4JVH

Note: The @media query max-width should be adjusted accordingly for the `navbar-toggleable-*` class used in the navbar.

- navbar-toggleable-xs - 544px
- navbar-toggleable-sm - 767px
- navbar-toggleable-md - 991px

**UPDATE:** The extra CSS is *no longer needed* as of Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 since the navbar will stack vertically: http://www.codeply.com/go/cCZz5CsMcD

Answer (score 0):

I have check many solutions available on internet but non of them works perfectly. finally after lot of search i found blow example working perfectly. all it has extra is few line of Jquery and css code.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/bootstrap-side-navbar/#five