# Bootstrap - Change breakpoint navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, breakpoints, nav, bootstrap-5

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329305/bootstrap-4-responsive-navbar) but this don't work because of the Javascript. So in the provided answer only the CSS was changed but not the JS, which means the content of the nav bar is still visible while the toggler is not. Any solution?

Edit:

My question is how to change the breakpoint of the nav bar in Bootstrap 4.xx

Comment: The other question was about stacking the items vertically once the navbar collapses, not the navbar collapse breakpoint.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5.0**

Bootstrap 5 still uses the `navbar-expand*` classes to determine the Navbar's collapse breakpoint. There is now an additional navbar-expand-xxl class.

[Bootstrap 5 - Navbar Tiers](https://codeply.com/p/xikQQGLYQd)

**Bootstrap 4.0.0**

Changing the navbar breakpoint is easier in Bootstrap 4 using the **`navbar-expand-*`** classes. If you exclude `navbar-expand-*` the mobile menu will be used at `all` widths. Here's a demo of all 6 navbar states: [Bootstrap 4 - Navbar Tiers](http://www.codeply.com/go/n4Pn4aB695)

Also see:
[Change bootstrap navbar collapse breakpoint without using LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827605/change-bootstrap-navbar-collapse-breakpoint-without-using-less/36289507)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did the job. I had to correct the CSS for the following class: ".navbar-nav .navbar-toggleable-xs.collapse".

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Bootstrap provide an easy way to work with menus. You can use `navbar-expand-xl`, `navbar-expand-lg`, `navbar-expand-md` etc according to your needs.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(Bootstrap 4 Beta compliant) If you want to have customized breakpoints, you can use this snippet from my own site. I copied one of the defined breakpoints and modified it to fit my needs. I had issues with the menu not being inline with the brand, but I fixed that by overriding the flex-wrap option. To implement, simply add to another CSS file or inline. Code:

```
@media (max-width:1070px){.navbar-expand-srset>.container,.navbar-expand-srset>.container-fluid{padding-right:0;padding-left:0}}@media (min-width:1071px){.navbar-expand-srset{-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:nowrap;flex-wrap:nowrap;-ms-flex-pack:start;justify-content:flex-start}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-nav{-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{position:absolute}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu-right{right:0;left:auto}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-nav .nav-link{padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.navbar-expand-srset>.container,.navbar-expand-srset>.container-fluid{-ms-flex-wrap:nowrap;flex-wrap:nowrap}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-collapse{display:-ms-flexbox!important;display:flex!important}.navbar-expand-srset .navbar-toggler{display:none}.navbar{flex-wrap:nowrap!important;-ms-flex-wrap:nowrap!important;}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I override the .navbar-expand-lg in native CSS.

Here is the example code:

```
    @media (min-width: *desired break point here){
.navbar-expand-lg {
    -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap !important;
    flex-flow: row nowrap !important;
    -ms-flex-pack: start !important;
    justify-content: flex-start !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
    flex-direction: row !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0.5rem !important;
    padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container,
  .navbar-expand-lg > .container-fluid {
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-collapse {
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto !important;
    flex-basis: auto !important;
  }
  .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
    display: none !important;
  }}
```