# bootstrap 4 - navigation menu issue on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Trying to learn website layouts creation using the newest `bootstrap 4 alpha 4` (in conjustion with `jQuery 3`) and in this question I would would like to cover 1 issue which I have come across so far.

1. When I click on "menu" button in navbar "collapsed mode" - drop down list drops in the center and then shifts to the left side. This looks awful. Problem explained:

[image]

Why does this happen and how do I force the list to to always **drop down from right side** instead (and stay there after animation)?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/1073/

**Edit:** in accepted solution there is no right align.. Note that in fiddle there is class `pull-xs-right` for navbar but it doesn't kick-in:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/1075/

So I went ahead and made my own solution by adding clearfix `div` before navbar:

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website</a>
  <div class="clearfix hidden-sm-up"></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar1">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed bottom</a> -->
        <div class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so in the end I am using this approach (no `CSS` changes required):

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/1077/

Comment: Please narrow this and clarify. It may need to be separate questions.

Comment: @ZimSystem point taken. Removed questions 2, 3 and 4. Now it's just one - the most important.

Comment: yes and no :) I marked your answer as correct but there is no right aligning as was requested in my question.. But i managed to fix it differently. See my update on how exactly i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has basically been answered here:
[Bootstrap 4 responsive navbar vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329305/bootstrap-4-responsive-navbar-vertical)

In Bootstrap 4, the navbar doesn't stack vertically by default so you have to add some CSS to make it work like Bootstrap 3.x..

```
@media(max-width:544px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
        float: none;
        margin-left: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
    }
    .navbar .collapse.in, .navbar .collapsing  {
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/iapESdPQ7k

**UPDATE:** The extra CSS is no longer needed for Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 since the navbar will stack vertically: http://www.codeply.com/go/cCZz5CsMcD